# Xdocreport generating file in IDE but not from a jar

Tags: java, xdocreport

I use xdocreport to generate a word file. In the IDE it's works fine but once i test my program as a runnable jar, the file is not generated anymore, instead i get the error

```
fr.opensagres.xdocreport.core.XDocReportException: Null template engine. Set template engine with IXDocReport#setTemplateEngine.
```

Same thing happens when i try a runnable jar with the tutoriel given in [the xdocreport projet](https://code.google.com/p/xdocreport/wiki/DocxReportingJavaMain)

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import fr.opensagres.xdocreport.core.XDocReportException;
import fr.opensagres.xdocreport.document.IXDocReport;
import fr.opensagres.xdocreport.document.registry.XDocReportRegistry;
import fr.opensagres.xdocreport.template.IContext;
import fr.opensagres.xdocreport.template.TemplateEngineKind;

public class testing {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      // 1) Load ODT file by filling Velocity template engine and cache it to the registry
      InputStream in = testing.class.getResourceAsStream("DocxProjectWithVelocity.docx");
      IXDocReport report = XDocReportRegistry.getRegistry().loadReport(in,TemplateEngineKind.Velocity);

      // 2) Create context Java model
      IContext context = report.createContext();
      Project project = new Project("XDocReport");
      context.put("project", project);

      // 3) Generate report by merging Java model with the ODT
      OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new    File("DocxProjectWithVelocity_out.docx"));
      report.process(context, out);

    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (XDocReportException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

The error seems to occure at the line :

```
 IXDocReport report = XDocReportRegistry.getRegistry().loadReport(in,TemplateEngineKind.Velocity);
```

any idea on how I can overcome this issue (at least with the tutorial)? I have tried putting the file in many different paths but it still can not be found by the runnable jar.

thank you

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with velocity in the runnable jar.
The key to fix this issue is written in the exception message:

```
Set template engine with IXDocReport#setTemplateEngine
```

For me works setting up the velocity to the `IXDocReport` (`ITemplateEngine` object)  and `FieldsMetadata` (`String` = "Velocity") objects.
The example of my code:

```
private void CreateTextFooterReportPdf(PdfFooterModel footerTemplate, String FullFilePath)
            throws IOException, FileNotFoundException, Exception {
    InputStream in = new FileInputStream("Path to your template Here");


    IXDocReport report = XDocReportRegistry.getRegistry().loadReport(in, TemplateEngineKind.Velocity);

    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty("resource.loader", "class");
    properties.setProperty(
            "class.resource.loader.class",               "org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader");


    ITemplateEngine templateEngine = new VelocityTemplateEngine(properties);

    report.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine);



    FieldsMetadata metadata = report.createFieldsMetadata();
    metadata.setTemplateEngineKind("Velocity");
```

.....

Hope if it will be helpful for someone.

Answer (score 0):

Switching from velocity to freemarker seems to have solved the problem.
instead of the line

```
IXDocReport report = XDocReportRegistry.getRegistry().loadReport(in,TemplateEngineKind.Velocity);
```

i used

```
IXDocReport report = XDocReportRegistry.getRegistry().loadReport(in,TemplateEngineKind.Freemarker);
```

as for the word file , in the mergefile instead of «$Project.name» i use «${Project.name}»

Hope this helps

Comment: Your problem its because you have not Velocity and/or their dependencies in your runnable JAR.

Answer (score 0):

add dependency
if you use maven

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>fr.opensagres.xdocreport</groupId>
        <artifactId>fr.opensagres.xdocreport.template.velocity</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
```